# BS3 - toggle icon class on collapse

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, toggleclass

I can't seem to figure out why this isn't toggling the icon class on click.  I am showing/hiding an accordion on click of the arrows, but I also want to toggle the font awesome icon to change the arrow at the same time (fa-angle-up / fa-angle-down).

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R6EAW/2243/)

html:

```
<ul id="archivegroup">
    <li class="panel">
        <a href="#alist0" data-parent="#archivegroup" data-toggle="collapse" class="accordion-toggle" aria-expanded="true"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a> <a href="/archive/2015">2015</a> <span class="count">(2)</span>
        <ul class="collapse in" id="alist0" aria-expanded="true" style="">
            <li>
                <a href="/archive/2015-09">September</a> <span class="count">(1)</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/archive/2015-05">May</a> <span class="count">(1)</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="panel">
        <a href="#alist1" data-parent="#archivegroup" data-toggle="collapse" class="accordion-toggle collapsed" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i></a> <a href="/archive/2013">2013</a> <span class="count">(1)</span>
        <ul class="collapse " id="alist1" aria-expanded="false">
            <li>
                <a href="/2013-09">September</a> <span class="count">(1)</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="panel">
        <a href="#alist2" data-parent="#archivegroup" data-toggle="collapse" class="accordion-toggle collapsed" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i></a> <a href="/archive/2010">2010</a> <span class="count">(1)</span>
        <ul class="collapse " id="alist2" aria-expanded="false">
            <li>
                <a href="/archive/2010-09">September</a> <span class="count">(1)</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

js:

```
function toggleChevron(e) {
    $(e.target)
        .prev('panel')
        .find("i.fa")
        .toggleClass('fa-angle-up fa-angle-down');
}
$('#archivegroup').on('hidden.bs.collapse', toggleChevron);
$('#archivegroup').on('shown.bs.collapse', toggleChevron);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't getting the `panel` class, since you have missed `.` plus you are trying to find `prev` element which I suspect will not consider `parent` instead it considers `siblings`, which it will not find. So use `.closest` to get `.panel` parent. So below are the changes:

```
function toggleChevron(e) {
    $(e.target).closest('.panel').find('i.fa')
        .toggleClass('fa-angle-up fa-angle-down');
}
$('#archivegroup').on('hidden.bs.collapse', toggleChevron);
$('#archivegroup').on('shown.bs.collapse', toggleChevron);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/R6EAW/2245/)**

Comment: Anytime.. Happy Coding.. :)

Comment: I'm trying, but things like this probably means I should sleep :)  Have a good one!

Comment: True that.. Sleep is very important before coding.. :)